# How to inject R matrix values as blocks into corresponding list objects while preserving names of list columns?

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'm trying to inject R matrix values into corresponding list objects which in the aggregate have the same dimensions, while preserving the column names embedded in the list objects and ignoring the column names of the free-standing matrixes. Matrixes values are injected into the corresponding lists as "blocks", without having to map out column names between the free-standing matrix and the corresponding list.

In my example, I have free standing matrix `mat1_tmp` whose values I would like to inject into its corresponding list, `list1_tmp`. I also show, for the sake of example, `mat2_tmp` whose values I'd like to inject into `list2_tmp` and `mat3_tmp` whose values I'd like to inject into `list3_tmp`. These 3 examples show the different list structures I am working with. Any recommendations for how to efficiently do this?

Immediately below are images showing what I'm trying to do. At the bottom is code for generating these examples matrixes and lists. FYI in the fuller code these examples derive from, I run calculations in matrixes and then consolidate the matrix values into lists for ease of reading values into a Shiny App.

Images for `mat1_tmp` - `list1_tmp` and `mat2_tmp` - `list2_tmp`:

[image]

Image for `mat3_tmp` - `list3_tmp`:

[image]

Code for the above matrixes and lists:

```
list1_tmp <- list(
  Top = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Avail", "A", "B")))
)

mat1_tmp <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
colnames(mat1_tmp) <- c("Cat","Dog","Boy")

list2_tmp <- list(
  Top = list(
    One = matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=3,dimnames = list(NULL,c("A","B","Total"))),
    Two = matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=2,dimnames = list(NULL,c("A","Total")))
  )
)

mat2_tmp <- matrix(7:16, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
colnames(mat2_tmp) <- c("Dog","Boy","Tom","Dog","Tom")

list3_tmp <- list(
  Top = list(
    One = list(
      A = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("AA", "BB", "CC"))),
      B = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("AA", "BB", "CC")))
    ),
    Two = list(
      A = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("AA", "BB", "CC"))),
      B = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("AA", "BB", "CC")))
    )
  )
)

mat3_tmp <- matrix(17:40, nrow = 2, ncol = 12)
colnames(mat3_tmp) <- rep(c("Sea","Pea","Tow"),4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1_tmp$Top[] <- mat1_tmp
```

This code does element-wise assignment. So, afterwards

```
list1_tmp$Top
     Avail A B
[1,]     1 3 5
[2,]     2 4 6
```

For unequal size import and export objects:

```
list3_tmp$Top$One$A[] <- mat3_tmp[1, 1:3]
```

The rest seems to be using loops or similar constructurs like `apply` or `map`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: OK this gets me started. This works where the dimensions are the same between the exporting matrix and the importing list, as in my example mat1_tmp exports to list1_tmp.

Comment: I added code for the case that the dimensions are not the same. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77331556/how-to-inject-r-matrix-values-as-blocks-into-corresponding-list-objects-while-pr for another way to solve this type of problem